# Showing iAds in SpriteKit Game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I get the following error when I try to ad iAds to my SpriteKit game. Anyone know why this is?

```
-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10da31fb0
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = NO;
        skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [HomeScreen sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];

        self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: we had this many times before, the iAd view is replacing the view controller's view (dunno how though), which should be an SKView and not an iAd view

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Ah I see. So what exactly is the solution?

Comment: 1) If you go only IOS7 you can use canDisplayBannerAds but in this case no need to alloc ADBannerView. (except medium rectangle ad) http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_iAds_into_an_iOS_7_App 2) If you dont develop exclusively to IOS7 then you do the ADBannerView view creation. More info on 1) regarding view hierarchy modification eg here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521677/what-does-the-iad-uiviewcontroller-category-candisplaybannerads-do

Comment: @codedad I do in fact only need to support iOS7+, however your #1 solution still causes my app to throw the same error. Are you sure that that works? I've edited my question as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment (regarding iAD) the error shows me that somehow to view's class is not correct. It should be `SKView`.

To correct this go to *Interface Builder* and for that particular view change the class using the *Identity inspector* (3rd "tab") to `SKView`.

It happened to me when manually created from the scratch a SpriteKit project.

Hope  it helps! :)