# UIView Error from implementing iAd

Tags: objective-c, uikit, sprite-kit, iad

I am trying to implement a very simple iAd into my game and I am getting an error. I am new to Xcode and have trouble reading error codes. I've tried the exact same method in a new SpriteKit project and it worked perfectly. I'm guessing this must have something to do with my game.

The error is as follows.

`2014-03-30 17:18:35.966 MyGame[672:60b] -[UIView setPaused:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa764120
2014-03-30 17:18:35.970 MyGame[672:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setPaused:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa764120'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x019901e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0170f8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01a2d243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0198050b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x019800ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   MyGame                              0x00012331 -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] + 225
    6   UIKit                               0x002a6ca6 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 329
    7   UIKit                               0x002ac891 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 1378
    8   UIKit                               0x002c0f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    9   UIKit                               0x002c1555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    10  UIKit                               0x002ae250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x025d9f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x025d9a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0190bca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0190b9db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0193668c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x019359d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x019357eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    18  UIKit                               0x002abd9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    19  UIKit                               0x002adf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    20  MyGame                              0x0001250d main + 141
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x02ad8701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

My ViewController.m is as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [StartGameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Comment: common problem, iAd replaces the view controller's view with its own, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521677/what-does-the-iad-uiviewcontroller-category-candisplaybannerads-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the ViewController.m I had in my original question was correct. What caused the problem were a few lines I put in my AppDelegate.m to pause the game. That is why I was getting the 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setPaused:]: error.

Here are two methods from my AppDelegate.m that contains the lines that caused the crash.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // pause sprite kit
    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.paused = YES;

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //resume sprite kit
    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.paused = NO;
}
```

I removed these 4 lines and everything worked. Many thanks to those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your code in viewWillLayoutSubViews...

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews 
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [StartGameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it still gives an error but a different one.  2014-03-30 18:09:39.610 MyGame[397:60b] -[UIView presentScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa7674a0
2014-03-30 18:09:39.618 MyGame[397:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView presentScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa7674a0'

Comment: When you comment out "self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;" does it run?

Comment: Also, have you imported iAd.h?

Comment: Also, where do you create your banner?

Comment: Also try adding "self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;" after "[skView presentScene:scene];".

Comment: If I comment out "self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;", yes it does run. Yes I have imported iAd.h. I would like to create the banner on the bottom of the screen. And if I put "self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;" after "[skView presentScene:scene];", I am still getting the error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView presentScene:]:

Comment: My ViewController.h and ViewController.m are pretty clean and is almost the same as the one from a new SpriteKit project other than the fact that I imported AVFoundation for sounds. I'm not sure how this works but do you think the problem might be coming from the code I have in another file?

Comment: I have added StartGameScene.m to the top. I removed the displayHighScore and displayCoinWallet methods just so save room. MyScene is the scene that you actually play the game on. I would like ads to show on StartGameScene and not MyScene.